# HttpRequest.HttpContext.User (ClaimsPrincipal) object in a Azure HttpTrigger Function does not contain my Identity from Authorization Header

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, bearer-token, .net-core-3.1, azure-http-trigger

```csharp
[FunctionName("GetDetails")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/{Id}/details")] HttpRequest request, int Id)
{
    //my code here to get claims from the User context (request.HttpContext.User).
}
```

I also tried injecting the ClaimsPrincipal object in my function like below:

```csharp
[FunctionName("GetDetails")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/{Id}/details")] HttpRequest request, int Id, **ClaimsPrincipal principal**)
{
    //my code here to get claims from the User context (request.HttpContext.User).
}
```

Still the same result.
For accessing the function locally I am passing my Bearer access token as below :
Authorization : Bearer

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: If it's anonymous authorization level what do you expect to see there?

Comment: Do you see access token when checked in the request headers `req.Headers["Authorization"]`?

Comment: yes i do. @user1672994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, using `request.HttpContext.User` can obtain the authentication information of the function protected by `AAD` in `Azure portal`.

I don't understand why you pass `Bearer` locally, but if you have this requirement, you can refer to the following code：

```
            req.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var headers);

            var authorization = headers.First();

            var jwt = authorization.Split(' ')[1];
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);
            var unique_name = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "unique_name").Value;
            log.LogInformation(unique_name);
```

You can refer to [Decode JWTs in C# for Authorization](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/26/decode-jwt-in-csharp-for-authorization).

Note:

If you encounter this error：

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. FunctionPa: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

You can add `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>` in the `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: thank you for this help..also did you find this anywhere in the docs that the authentication part will be handled on azure but not locally?

Comment: If you use `AAD` to protect your `Function`, you can directly use `request.HttpContext.User` in `portal`. If you don’t use `AAD` protection, you can use the code I recommend, regardless of local or ` Portal` is fine.

Comment: in that case i must use AuthorizationLevel.User, right?

Comment: AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous is also possible.